# Ambiguity with `quote` in the Little Schemer. When should an expression be proceeded with a quote and when shouldn't it?

Tags: scheme, the-little-schemer

The Little Schemer 4e by Friedman and Felleisen starts out by defining `atom?`:

```
(define atom?
    (lambda (x)
        (and (not (pair? x)) (not (null? x)))))
```

Then in the first chapter there's questions asking if so and so is a atom or not. E.g. (the footnote is rephrased for clarity):

> Is it true that this is an atom?
>
> `atom`*
>
> *in Scheme: `(quote atom)` or `'atom`

It says `turkey`, `1492`, `u`, and `*abc$` are also atoms.

All of these except `1492` must be preceded by a `'` - otherwise we get a `Error: execute: unbound symbol:`

`1492` and `'1492` both work. Henceforth, in this book, how do I know when something should or should not be preceded by a quote (`'`)??? It's confusing. I wish the authors had just been explicit with the quotes -- does it really add that much visual noise to have a single quote (`'`) precede expressions??? Should I just assume everything is preceded by a quote (`'`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atoms. An atom is an indivisible thing. A value like `13` or `72` is indivisible, it is a single value. There are other atoms, a string like `"hello"`, a variable like `x` or `y`, a value like `:keyword` or `'something`.

When Lisp is written, atoms are separated by spaces or parentheses. We can then create one or more `form` by putting atoms within parentheses, for example `(* 2 (+ 1 3))`. The atoms here are:

- operators + and *
- values 1, 2 and 3
- forms (+ 1 3) and (* 2 ...)

There are then a couple of problems. For starters, with `x` do we mean the atom `'x`, a variable called `x`, or the value stored within the variable `x`? Lisp assumes that `x` is a variable and so typing `x` returns the value of `x` or produces an error about `x` being unbound. Putting a single  quote in front of `x`, as `'x`, says "please don't try to evaluate this".

Forms have a consistent format `(operator data1 data2 data3 ...)`. But what happens if you just want to supply data? What operator do you use? The answer is to use operator `quote`, which evaluates the form to just the data. Because saying quote all of the time is annoying, Lisp allows you to say`'(data1 data2 data3 ...)` instead.

As for `'1492`, this is the same as `1492` in Scheme and Common Lisp. The values are interchangeable. I would use `1492` since the quote is superfluous.